# Get post value of different option

Tags: php, sql

[different option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTLQI.png)

I have three option as you can see. And I only need the Course option and Year option. Now I want to get their values so that I can pass them into my query. The problem here, they've been queried based on different tables and when I tried passing the $_POST of the Section into a variable and query it, the error says that undefined index. What should I do? Thanks

This is the code of the two options:

```
<div class="col-md-3 pull right">
              <label>Course</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="course" id="courseselect">
                    <?php
                         $query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM course");
                         $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
                      if($numrows !=0 ){
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {?>
                           <option value="<?php echo $row['courseid'];?>"><?php echo $row['coursedesc'];?></option>
                          <?php } 
                        }
                      ?> 

                </select>
                </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 pull right">
             <label>Year</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="year">
                   <?php
                     $query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM year");
                    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
                   if($numrows !=0 ){
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {?>
                          <option ><?= $row['yearnum'];?></option>
                          <?php } 
                        }
                  ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and this is my query

```
$cid=$_POST['courseid'] //the value from the Course option
SELECT t1.studentno, t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.yearid, t2.coursedesc
                    FROM
                        students as t1
                        INNER JOIN course as t2
                            ON $cid=t2.courseid
                        LEFT JOIN paidstudents as t3
                            ON t1.studentno = t3.studentno
                    WHERE
                        t1.studentno IS NOT NULL
                        AND t3.studentno IS  NULL
```

$cid says undefined index

I want to replace the courseid and yearid into the post values above. Thank you

Comment: on the php/html part with the select : what does your form look like ? on the php part : how do you get the $vars (post/get method) and how do you take care of verifying ?

Comment: Where is the PHP code that you post to and use the selected values?

Comment: This my form looks like https://ibb.co/bPKAbQ @OldPadawan

Comment: @SloanThrasher I haven't use my option before, the reason why I'm using it is for filtering data in the table

Comment: @Blances : not the output, the code please ^^

Comment: I'm talking about the code you refer to that you are getting the error in. Also, mark the line with the error so we don't have to count lines. The part that assigns the $_POST to a variable. BTW, $_POST is an array, with one element for each item posted to the server.

Comment: @OldPadawan here it is https://gist.github.com/blancessanchez/9e2b3cf6d8e4c4170efaba0803bf0d7e

Comment: this is what I did that's why I'm getting error:

$cid=$_POST['courseid'];

SELECT t1.studentno, t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.yearid, t2.coursedesc
                    FROM
                        students as t1
                        INNER JOIN course as t2
                            ON t1.courseid=t2.courseid
                        LEFT JOIN paidstudents as t3
                            ON $cid = t3.studentno
                    WHERE
                        t1.studentno IS NOT NULL
                        AND t3.studentno IS  NULL

 $cid, it says that undefined index

Comment: `<form id="indiv" method="get"> -> $cid=$_POST['courseid'];` if your form uses a GET method you need to use a GET response `$course = $_GET['course']; $year = $_GET['year'];

Comment: @OldPadawan I don't get it po

Comment: If I'll passed it into the query, will I get the value?

Comment: @OldPadawan this is the error I get https://ibb.co/ht7wGQ

Comment: you need to echo your $vars `before` any use if the local / pre-prod stage process. EDIT: here, you try to use $courseid and $yearid, but where are they defined ?

Comment: this is the updated code

https://gist.github.com/blancessanchez/9e2b3cf6d8e4c4170efaba0803bf0d7e

Comment: too much code :( let's try to be clear : you have everything on the same page, and it's quite a mess (sorry to say so...). you have `<form method="POST" action="paymethod.php"> <?php $cid=$_POST['courseid'];  $yid=$_POST['yearid']; ?>` Q: where is the form sending `courseid / yearid` ? Nowhere I can see the input/data to be sent. You want to send data to paymethod.php ? then, in the form, you need to set `courseid / yearid` and on `paymethod.php` you can use `$couseid = $_POST['courseid'];  $yearid = $_POST['yearid'];`

Answer (score 0):

Your form select is:

```
<select class="form-control" name="course" id="courseselect">
```

so the posted field will be `course` but in your code you do:

```
$cid=$_POST['courseid']
```

So either

```
$cid = $_POST['course'];
```

or

```
<select class="form-control" name="courseid" id="courseselect">
```

To make the form field name match the POST variable you try to access.

Comment: Did you get the same error or something else?
Oh and there is another question, you didn't post the full form, so I coudln't see but did oyu set the form method to POST?

Comment: yeah same error, this is the code: https://gist.github.com/blancessanchez/9e2b3cf6d8e4c4170efaba0803bf0d7e

yes i did, set the form to post

Comment: This gist still has the select with name="course" but asking for $_POST['courseid'] this cannot work.